# Licensing problem with ClickOnce application

Tags: deployment, licensing, clickonce

I've got a 3rd party video capture control in my system ([LeadTools Capture control](http://leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/capture.htm)), which is licensed and works perfectly in my Dev environment.

When it's deployed as a ClickOnce app, however, it bombs out with the following error:

[image]

What could the problem be, and how do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heya bud,
Not at all familiar with that control, of course, but near as I can tell it relies on an ActiveX / COM component - which requires registration.

However, ClickOnce does not support registration of COM components. (This is because of the sandboxing model it has in place). Thats why its crashing, since the COM component isn't - and cannot be - registered.

Check out these links for how to get around it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165432(v=VS.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx

Comment: Thanks bro! Always a pleasure to see you online... and offline too I guess... ;)